# Java: how to check if a program has been correctly launched?

Tags: java, xml, windows, command-line, command

I am developping a little Java jar application for storage data in file.xml using BaseX server.
AT the beginning, before the main program starts, I need that Basex Server is correctly launched and activated. So here is what I do:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

if (isWindows(os)) {
    Process server = runtime.exec("cmd /C basexserver.bat");
    System.out.println(server.waitFor());

}

else {
    if (isLinux(os)) {
        runtime.exec("basexserver");
    }
}
```

To check if BaseXServer is correctly running I have tried to check the value returned by waitFor method and if this value is equal to 0 then the command was successfully executed while if the returned value is greater than 0 then an error has occurred. The problem is that this method always returns 1 but the command "basexserver.bat" is correct. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If process goes into background after start, you can check `exitValue()` to be zero. Secondly you can attache to error and standard outputs with methods `getErrorStream()` and `getInputStream()`. And monitor them for error messages. have a look at stream gobbler pattern also, it could be useful. Some process can stuck if it's output is not consumed.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I am afraid this does not work because "basexserver.bat" launches the server which will never stop until the main program is closed...so I cannot call waitFor after Process server = runtime.exec("cmd /C basexserver.bat"); otherwise my program will block until the server is stopped and so it is not possible to use it

Comment: In this case you have to monitor error stream. Make a regexp matcher, which will alert you in case of error.

Comment: maybe I am making confusion...what I need to check is that the command was successfully executed...I cannot check exit value after launching baseX server because I would get "java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process has not exited"...I want the server to be running as far as the main program is being used

Comment: If the program has not exited yet, the only way is to check output.

Comment: Ok, this is what I'm gonna do. Thank you :)